# different radio button have different audio file paths but how to play it?

Tags: javascript, php, html

there is the code,

```
<html>
<title>Play</title>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function get_radio_value() {
        var inputs = document.getElementsByName("selected");
        for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
          if (inputs[i].checked) {
            return inputs[i].value;
          }
        }
      }

      function onSubmit() {
        var id = get_radio_value();
        var audio = new Audio(id);
        audio.play();
      }
    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <form onsubmit="onSubmit();">
        <input name="selected" value="voicemail/default/user/INBOX/msg0.wav" type="radio"/>msg0.wav<br/>
        <input name="selected" value="voicemail/default/user/INBOX/msg0.gsm" type="radio"/>msg0.gsm<br/>
        <input name="selected" value="voicemail/default/user/INBOX/msg0.mp3" type="radio"/>msg0.mp3<br/>
        <input type="submit" value="play"/>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I need to play the selected audio file when the play button hits

but it not works

if it is done by using php, please give php code

Answer (score 0):

You need to insert the audio files in your page, or load the by AJAX. Then do a 
`document.getElementById("audiofileid").play()`.

Reference: http://www.ehow.com/how_8546693_use-javascript-play-mp3-file.html